# Can a plot be animated by time with ggplotly when time(date) is x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I got excellent help setting up a `ggplotly` for  `geom_line` in [Where to properly position ggplotly tooltip in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75379845/where-to-properly-position-ggplotly-tooltip-in-ggplot)

My goal is to animate it, if possible, such that as the date progresses the two lines lengthen. To the `ggplot` I added `frame = activity_date,` to the `aes`.

```r
`library(tidyverse)
library("lubridate")
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
library(plotly)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'plotly'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     last_plot
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     layout
library("RColorBrewer")
library(htmlwidgets)
library("reprex")


activity <- c("N", "FB", "N", "N", "N", "FA", "N", "FA", "N", "FA", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "FA", "N", "N", "N", "N", "FA", "N", "N", "FA", "FA")

activity_date <- as.Date(c(NA, "2022-04-19", "2022-05-01", "2022-05-01", "2022-05-06", "2022-05-06", "2022-05-07", "2022-05-07", "2022-05-09", "2022-05-09", "2022-05-10", "2022-05-13", "2022-05-14", "2022-05-14", "2022-05-14", "2022-05-15", "2022-05-15", "2022-05-15", "2022-05-15", "2022-05-15", "2022-05-16", "2022-05-16", "2022-05-16", "2022-05-16", "2022-05-16"))

fcrawl_cum <- c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L)

clutch_cum <- c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L)

turtle_activity_gtm <- tibble(activity, activity_date, fcrawl_cum, clutch_cum)

the_pal <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 8,"Dark2") #Set color palette. 

turtle_activity_gtm_long <- turtle_activity_gtm %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(c(fcrawl_cum, clutch_cum))

ggplot() +
  geom_line(
    data = turtle_activity_gtm_long,
    aes(
      x = activity_date, y = value, 
      color = name, group = name, frame = activity_date,
      text = paste(
        "Date: ", as.Date(activity_date),
        "<br>Total: ", value
      )
    ),
    na.rm = TRUE,
    linewidth = 1.5
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(clutch_cum =  the_pal[[7]], fcrawl_cum = the_pal[[6]])) +
  labs(title = "myplot2")
#> Warning in geom_line(data = turtle_activity_gtm_long, aes(x = activity_date, :
#> Ignoring unknown aesthetics: frame and text`
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Upon using `ggplotly(tooltip = c("text"))`, I get this initial plot with *show closest data on*
[image]

And as soon as the time advances all plotting disappears even though the data points show up when hovering.
[image]

Is is possible to achieve my goal here?